# Outlook task doesn't accept automaticaly

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, tasks

I have created an outlook task. I assigned that task to another user, and the user gets an email saying to accept the task instead of just getting it.

There is a problem here:

- The user needs to accept the task, and I don't want that. I want the task to be automatically accepted.

How do i solve this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

*I assigned that task to another user, and the user gets an email saying to accept the task instead of just getting it.*

That is the way Outlook Calendar items and tasks work. Receiver must be able to decline a task or calendar entry.

Comment: Isn't there a way to force the user to accept it?

Comment: So far as I know (years of use with Outlook), user must accept and cannot be forced as there may be reasons to decline.  Management issue really